# Reading Registry DWORD

Tags: c#, registry

This code below checking if MySQL is installed works perfectly.

```
    public bool MySql()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\MySQL AB\\MySQL Server 5.6"))
            {
                var keyObject = key?.GetValue("installed");

                var keyToString = keyObject?.ToString();

                if (keyToString == "1")
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

However using the exact same code I try to see if OpenSSL is installed.

```
    public bool OpenSsl()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\OpenSSL (64-bit)_is1"))
            {
                var keyObject = key?.GetValue("NoModify");

                var keyToString = keyObject?.ToString();

                if (keyToString == "1")
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Setting breakpoints in the code revealed that key is returning null. I'm not sure why. Yes the path is correct.

Comment: You are perhaps reading the wrong registry. Is this an entry in the 64-bit registry or in the 32-bit registry? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS is routed to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node. To read the 64-bit version of the key, we need to use the `RegistryView`

**C# 4.0 code sample**

```
public static RegistryKey GetRegistryKey(string keyPath)
    {
        RegistryKey localMachineRegistry
            = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                      Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
                                          ? RegistryView.Registry64
                                          : RegistryView.Registry32);

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyPath)
            ? localMachineRegistry
            : localMachineRegistry.OpenSubKey(keyPath);
    }
```

If your using .NET 3.5 or below p/invoke is the only solution.

http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about 32 and 64-bit registries.

Comment: I have updated with a bit more explanation and an alternative for .NET 3.5 and below.